# Problem with linking glew with CodeLite

Tags: linker, mingw, glew

I've been trying to link glew to my c++ CodeLite project on Windows with little success. First I used MinGW to compile the glew source into libglew32.a and glew32.dll. These are inside C:/glew-1.6.0/lib.

Inside the project settings, the include path in the compiler tab is C:/glew-1.6.0/include and inside the linker tab I have C:/glew-1.6.0/lib under the library paths. For the linker options I have -lglew.

At this point I haven't even included glew inside main.cpp or written any code relating to glew. But when I run the program it gets stuck, leaving me the single output message: "Running program: ./TestProgram" while nothing happens.

When I remove the -lglew flag from the linker options, the program runs fine. Something seems to be wrong with how I've linked glew, but I don't know what.